# Forward requesting IP from Nginx to Apache's logs

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, virtualhost

I'm using nginx as a front end reverse proxy for Apache, I have the following configuration inside of nginx:

```
location / {
  if (-f $request_filename) {
      add_header X-Static hit;
      access_log off;
    }

  if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8000;
      add_header X-Static miss;
    }
```

With apache listening on port 8000 locally. When I look at apache's logs all the requests come from 127.0.0.1:443 (which is where nginx is sitting). I want to forward the real IP to apache so that it stores it properly in the logs.

I tried adding the following lines to the location block to no avail

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Am I missing a step here? Do I need to change apache's log format? It is currently using the default combined log.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but your config would be a bit cleaner without the ifs (assuming you're on 0.7+):  location / { add_header X-Static hit; access_log off; try_files $uri @apache; } location @apache { add_header X-Static miss; proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8000; }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to change apache's log format to support x-forward

for example

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{X-Forwarded-For}i" combined
```

Then you can use

```
 CustomLog logs/access_log combined
```

So the last entry in your log will be the header nginx is setting for the real IP. Of course you can switch around the order in the LogFormat line

Comment: **THIS IS WRONG**. X-Forwarded for can be multi-valued - each proxy in a chain should add the client address it sees. If you are trying to add the information in a new column then it should be delimited using quotes or brackets. If you want a single value for the client address, use X-Real-IP. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [mod_rpaf apache module](http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/)

On deb/ubuntu you can install package name libapache2-mod-rpaf

Once installed, add your nginx IP to the RPAFproxy_ips setting in /etc/apache2/mods-available/rpaf.conf

```
<IfModule mod_rpaf.c>
RPAFenable On RPAFsethostname 
On RPAFproxy_ips 127.0.0.1   
</IfModule>
```

Restart apache & you should see the correct IP addresses in your logs.

I'd keep this in place in your nginx config as well:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only changing HTTP header not the way how Apache see the connection ( from Nginx ).